# Adding div to row in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with templates something like this:

```
<asp:GridView class="TableContainer" ID="prodGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    EmptyDataText="No products" GridLines="None" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="prodGrid_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="prodGrid_RowDataBound" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="Grid">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectProduct" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectedProduct_CheckChanged" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgProd" ImageUrl="" AlternateText="image" runat="server" >
                </asp:Image>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle CssClass="Footer" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

In the html mark up it creates a table with rows, I would like to add a div on demand so that i can put a message in there or add a  spanning both columns. The message wont fit in one of the cells, so it will look something like this:

```
Product    |      Image  |
-------------------------
Bananas        [image]


So if they select the bananas product and it doesnt have enough stock,
 i would like to insert something like

Product   |    Image    |
-------------------------
Bananas        [image]
--- DIV WITH MESSAGE SHOWS HERE ACCROSS THE GRID---
```

once they fix the quantity i will hid it. I just want to know how i can insert a div given the grid above (there will be multiple rows) so when it can show the message on multiple products. I just would like some advice or idea on how to handle it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you must use a GridView control? If not, you could accomplish this fairly easily using a Repeater and the OnItemDataBound method. If you need the bells and whistles, then you might want to consider something more advanced, such as DevExpress Grid control: http://goo.gl/2dcm3O

Comment: Yes makes sense, unfortunatelly i can't change it :(, thanks for the advise though

Comment: Would a browser-side javascript solution be acceptable to whoever's setting your requirements on this? It's a bit of a dirty hack IMHO, but it would get the job done if you're not permitted to try a more elegant solution. Use a HiddenField control in one of your columns to store the message, if there is one. Use javascript to step through the hidden fields and test to see if they have a message. If there is one, inject a row into the table just after the HiddenField's parent row. Set colspan and style information on the cell accordingly and then you're done.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: Try to stay away from solutions that are dependent on the <table> HTML element. I'm not a designer myself so don't entirely understand the problem.  But for some reason, <table> elements make web designers unhappy. The designers I've work with are always *VERY HAPPY* whenever I transition HTML structures from <table> to <div> elements instead, and I've noticed they're usually more productive when they're happy. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using another image in your `TemplateField`, such as an alert type icon (read: exclamation point) that will be dynamically shown, along with a tool tip when the user hovers over the image, if the correct criteria are met, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgProd" ImageUrl="" AlternateText="image" runat="server">
        </asp:Image>
        <asp:Image ID="alertProd" ImageUrl="" AlternateText="alert" 
                   runat="server" Visible="False">
        </asp:Image>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Note: We make the alert image invisible, because it will be optionally shown by logic in the `RowDataBound` event for the grid view, like this:

```
protected void prodGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Check conditions here for whether or not to show alert image
        if(ShowAlertImage)
        {
            Image theAlertImage = e.Row.FindControl("alertProd") as Image;

            // Make sure we found the Image control before we try to set its tooltip
            if(theAlertImage != null)
            {
                theAlertImage.ToolTip = "Quantity is too low";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when the user mouses over the alert image, then they will see the message informing them of the problem with the product.